# Inverse of n-dimensional numpy.gradient

Tags: numpy, scipy

Does numpy or scipy contain a function which is an inverse of the n-dimensional "gradient" fn?

E.g. if "image" contains a 2D matrix, then i want a function inv_gradient that behaves as follows:

```
(gx, gy) = numpy.gradient(image)
constant_vector_0 = image[0,:] - inv_gradient(gx, gy)[0,:]
constant_vector_1 = image[:,0] - inv_gradient(gx, gy)[:,0]
image == inv_gradient(gx, gy) + tile(constant_vector_0,(shape(image)[0],1)) + transpose(tile(constant_vector_1,(shape(image)[1],1)))
```

Comment: Won't the original image be non-unique? For example, take any image that gave you those gradients and add a constant to it. In vector calculus, you can only really do this for a conservative vector field anyway, and you usually have undetermined functions in the integral. A real image, which is absolutely not a scalar field that produces a conservative gradient (just think of edge discontinuities) probably doesn't support this inversion process.

Comment: I don't understand why a real image is not a scalar field -- couldn't you take the scalar field to be the image surrounded by an infinite grid of zeros? The gradient of this should have zero curl. I'll edit the question to allow for the addition of a constant vector along each axis.

Comment: One approach I am aware of is research on reconstructing the image if you assume it is harmonic. Basically, you compute the Laplacian from the gradients, and you can solve for unknowns about the original image under the assumption that the Laplacian should be zero. This is by no means an easy optimization problem, and the results are usually not good because almost no real world image is even approximately harmonic. There may be other identifying assumptions, such as minimized total variation or something, but it's highly doubtful that SciPy has a built in for these complex reconstructions.

Comment: A real image is a scalar field. It's just not a continuous scalar field, hence its gradient is not conservative. Basically, infinite families of images with different similar edge structure could give rise to the same gradients. You have to make additional assumptions, like zero-laplacian, or minimized total variation, etc., to pick out one image from that infinite family.

Comment: hmm... in my application i am starting with an image, taking the gradient, modifying the gradient slightly, and then i want to get back a modified image. In particular, i am trying to remove artifacts from data, and the artifacts are detected as gradients in certain directions at certain positions in the image. Perhaps there is a good choice for this special case. Otoh perhaps it would be simpler just to make the modifications to the original image after the artifacts are detected.

Comment: Imagine an image that has an all-black background, a large gray circle, and a smaller white circle inside of the gray one. Inside of each of the circles, the gradient is zero, as it is on the background. The only non-zero gradients are at the circle boundaries. You couldn't get a constant offset as in your modified question. The relative intensity of the difference circles would just be destroyed by the gradient filter.

Comment: The gradient is not a transform like Fourier or Laplace... so if you mess with the computed gradient, you've destroyed the correspondence to the original image in a whole region around those edited spots. My suggestion would, first see if you can find the artifacts as frequency-dependent in the Fourier domain and filter them there, or perhaps with Wavelets. The next try would be to detect them using your gradient checking, but then to modify the image. If the artifacts are small, you could delete those pixels and then use a harmonic filter to smooth in to match the surrounding image pixels.

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is basically an inverse filter.  These exist, but are limited.

One way to understand this is via the [convolution theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem), and to think of the gradient as a particular kernel for a convolution, in this case something like (-1, 0, 1) in 1D.  The issue then, is that the Fourier Transform (FT) of the kernel will have zeroes, and that when the FTs of the kernel and signal are multiplied, the zeroes in the kernel's FT wipes out any data from the original data in this part of the spectrum (and this gets more problematic when noise is added to the image).  Specifically for the gradient, there is 0 power in the f=0 band, and this is what people are referring to in the comments, but other information is lost as well.

Still, though, you can get a lot out of an inverse filter, and maybe what you need.  It's fairly case specific.

[Here's](http://ecourses.vtu.ac.in/nptel/courses/Webcourse-contents/IIT-KANPUR/Digi_Img_Pro/chapter_9/9_18.html) a very basic and quick description of the issue, and an [example](http://www.gergltd.com/cse485/project4/) (though not for gradients).