# Function to compute inverse of numpy.gradient

Tags: python, numpy, gradient

I have a Gaussian and I compute its gradient using `numpy.gradient` function. I want to make slight changes in the gradient and get back a slightly modified Gaussian.

[image: Gaussian and its gradient]

Is there any function in python which can calculate the inverse of the gradient?

I already checked this link [Inverse of n-dimensional numpy.gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272245/inverse-of-n-dimensional-numpy-gradient) but could not find the solution.

Comment: You would have to integrate, but you will propably suffer from inacuracies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `1D` the following snippet reverses `np.gradient`:

```
>>> A = scipy.stats.norm().pdf(np.linspace(-1, 1, 19))
>>> A
array([0.24197072, 0.26874286, 0.29481487, 0.31944801, 0.34189229,
       0.36142383, 0.37738323, 0.38921247, 0.39648726, 0.39894228,
       0.39648726, 0.38921247, 0.37738323, 0.36142383, 0.34189229,
       0.31944801, 0.29481487, 0.26874286, 0.24197072])
>>> 
>>> a = np.gradient(A)
>>> 
>>> A[0] + 2 * np.c_[np.r_[0, a[1:-1:2].cumsum()], a[::2].cumsum() - a[0] / 2].ravel()[:len(a)]
array([0.24197072, 0.26874286, 0.29481487, 0.31944801, 0.34189229,
       0.36142383, 0.37738323, 0.38921247, 0.39648726, 0.39894228,
       0.39648726, 0.38921247, 0.37738323, 0.36142383, 0.34189229,
       0.31944801, 0.29481487, 0.26874286, 0.24197072])
```

Comment: Nice! I am wondering if I could apply this to a 2D situation? My example is here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63220629/inverse-of-numpy-gradient-function)